# No consigo el valor de un fetch

Tags: javascript, promesas, asincronismo

Estoy intentando conseguir el valor que me retorna un fetch y no estoy consiguiendo.
Este es el código

```js
function getData() {
    let url = 'https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=1&length=5&type=uppercase'
    fetch (url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {return data[0]})}

function showData() {
    let api = getData();
    console.log(api);
    return api
}

showData()
```

Me sale siempre undefined, y cambiando de api pasa lo mismo, quisiera saber cual exactamente es mi error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no te falta un await ahi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes 2 errores:

- La función `getData` no devuelve nada, es decir, falta hacer `return` de algo.
- La API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) realizas una llamada asincrónica, por lo que devuelve una [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). A raíz de esto tenés 2 opciones, usar:

  1. [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
  2. [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

#### Ejemplo usando la opción # 1

```js
function getData() {
    let url = 'https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=1&length=5&type=uppercase'
    return fetch (url) // <- 1) hacemos return
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => data[0])
}

// 2) definimos funcion async
async function showData() {
    let api = await getData(); // 3) así podemos usar await
    console.log(api);
    return api
}

showData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas trabajando con promesas, las promesas no pueden "retornar" lo que haces es suscribirte y para acceder al dato tienes que hacerlo dentro del `then`

si quieres hacerlo fuera del `then` tienes que hacerlo a través de otra función

```js
let url = 'https://random-word-api.vercel.app/api?words=1&length=5&type=uppercase';


function getData() {
    fetch (url)
    .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.info('getData', data));
}

getData()

async function asyncGetData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

asyncGetData().then(d=> console.info('asyncGetData', d));

function writeToContainer(data) {
  document.getElementById('container').innerText = data;
}

asyncGetData().then(d=> writeToContainer(d[0]));
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```